# Setting hostname via scutil

Tags: command-line

When following various guides on using `scutil` the following would seem to be correct for setting the hostname:

```
$sudo scutil –-set HostName doriath
>
```

But as you can see instead of setting the hostname a prompt `>` is shown: and the hostname is *not* set.  What is wrong here?  I am on `El Capitan`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prompt is the interactive mode of scutil which usually is invoked by the single command `scutil` without options. To quit the interactive mode enter `quit` at the prompt.

In your case you are simply using the wrong dash: probably the en-dash (UTF-8: U+2013 - e2 80 93) and a normal dash and your whole command is interpreted as `scutil` only.

Instead of `sudo scutil –-set HostName doriath` use `sudo scutil --set HostName doriath`!

Comment: ya - looks like I missed replacing one of the two dashes from the cut and paste.

Answer (score 2):

Try these additional commands to get your system renamed AND put double quotes around the name in each instance:

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName "doriath"

sudo scutil --set HostName "doriath"

sudo scutil --set LocalHostName "doriath"
```

This has worked for me several times. Hope it does for you too.

Comment: Thx I had tried with quotes already as well and same result as OP

Comment: The behavior in my case  *is* strange .  I can't understand the failure mode to end up in some kind of completion shell.

Comment: Try using the su [your username] command string before the other 3 commands.