# macOS: Wrong Bonjour name stuck in hostname

Tags: macos, network, bonjour

Due to a network problem, my iMac was renamed Theater-ATV-8.localname.  This is the name that appears when the Terminal `hostname` name is run.

Nothing I have tried will change this name permanently. I can change it with `hostname [new name]`, but it reverts on reboot.

The name in the Sharing pane in System Preferences if `KW-desk-iMAC`.

Answer (score 2):

The man page for `hostname` says:

> To keep the hostname between reboots, run `scutil --set HostName name-of-host'.

Also, the name in the Sharing prefs pane you mentioned, is that the name that isvisible right there when you open the pane, or the one you can edit when you click the "Edit..." (or similar - in German it's "Bearbeiten...") button?

Answer (score 2):

Use `scutil` to set all three of the names that can exist for a macOS system.

[Setting hostname via scutil](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/263352/setting-hostname-via-scutil)

you can experiment with using a different name for each and figure which bonjour uses, which is the formal name and which maps to `hostname` if the manual page isn’t clear.